# What is the difference between these two methods of dynamic allocation of arrays?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, array-pointer

I was going through array using pointers and I found two different dynamic allocation methods of an array

```
int *ptr_arr=new int[10];
```

This one was defined in the lectures but when I explored a bit I found a slightly different method:

```
int **ptr_arr=new *int[10];
```

Can someone please explain what's the difference between them?

Comment: Do you want 10 `int` or 10 `int*`? `int` is an integer while `int*` is a pointer that can be made to point to an integer. The two are as different as `new int[10]` and `new double[10]`, just the types look a bit similar.

Comment: The second snippet does not even compile: `new *int[10]` ==> `new int*[10]`

Comment: Pretty much the same difference as between `int arr[10];` and `int* arr[10];`.

Comment: Basically the expression in general looks like this: `T* ptr = new T[10];`.  You are creating a dynamic array of type `T`.  What is `T` in both of the examples you have in the question?  Maybe that clears things up?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux, @PaulMcKenzie  I think I understand now, I am looking to get 10 `int` so the first one gives me a pointer pointing to an array of 10 `int` while the second one gives me 10 `int*` that is int pointers. Did I get it right?

Comment: @Priyanshu Seems like you got it right. In practice, use `std::vector<int`> if you need a dynamic array of `int`. In general don't use `new` in modern C++. Almost every time you would want to use `new` you can instead use `std::vector` or `std::make_unique`.